# Building libiconv in 64-bit mingw environment

Tags: mingw

I am trying to organize a little 64-bit gnu environment on my Windows PC. I have built 64-bit mingw environment, and went on to build libraries i needed next.

When building libiconv, i have tried following this [instruction](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw64_how_to.html#libiconv), which amounted to configuring with supplying `--host` parameter to configuration cipt. However, build failed with following error:

> c:/mingw_mine/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-min
>   gw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `.libs/libiconv.res.o' is incom
>   patible with i386:x86-64 output

What went wrong?

Some necessary details: i use precompiled 32-bit msys for shell. It includes number of programs, `make`, `install` and `gcc` included. To avoid using wrong `gcc`, i have first added necessary paths to PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, then performed configuration with:

> $ ../src/configure --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 CPPFLAGS="-Wall -I/c/mingw_mine/include" LDFLAGS="-L/c/mingw_mine/lib"

As far as i could tell, configuration script detected compiler i wanted correctly; all in all configuration went through without a problem. Where did i386 binaries came from? Even if configuration detected architecture with `uname` (`/bin/uname` in 32-bit msys), why would it matter if the host is defined explicitely?

Comment: I have so many problems with mingw latest years, that finally I changed back to cygwin64. Against mingw it has a _unique_, _standard_ and _working_ 64-bit version, while the to me important advantage of the mingw (the absence of the /cygdrive .. directories) are from the mingw also long gone.

Comment: i only have problems with building some things so far. What else should i expect?
P.S. Oh, and make does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, i haveresolved the issue. Step-by-step it goes:

1. I was getting wrong binaries as output of the `windres` program. Checking with `which` gave me `/bin/windres`, that is, one from 32-bit msys environment.
2. i have compiled bintools for 64-bit mingw, so i did have 64-bit windres in `/mingw/bin` folder. However, it was not used in the build process.
3. After checking how configuration process went, i have noticed lines like

> checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.... no
>
> checking for windres.... windres

4. I have created and put into /mingw folder of msys environment file named x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres with following contents:

   #!/bin/sh
   script="$0"
   basename="$(dirname $script)"
   $basename/windres "$@"

After reconfiguration, build went through smoothly.